# Questions regarding the input dimensionality of Embeddings in Keras based on official documentation

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, nlp

I have been reading the Keras tutorial published in Jonathan Hui Blog (https://jhui.github.io/2018/02/11/Keras-tutorial/) which as he states draws directly from the official Keras documentation.

There are parts of the code I don't quite understand and these relate to the dimensions of the Embedding layers.

Let's look at two examples:

**First Example:**

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import LSTM

import numpy as np

max_features = 10
x_train = np.random.random((1000, max_features))
y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=(1000, 1))
x_test = np.random.random((100, max_features))
y_test = np.random.randint(2, size=(100, 1))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, output_dim=256))
model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=10)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=16)
```

Here X is a matrix (1000 x 10) containing random numbers, each of one of them potentially unique.  However the Embedding layers receives as argument for input dimensions max_features (i.e. 10 in this example).  But when we pass input dimensions to an Embedding layers are n't we counting the unique possible values of the variable we are encoding?  To put it in other words, is n't the number of columns that would result from dummifying the variable on the basis of an assumption regarding the Dimensionality of the Space from which its values originate (e.g. a Vocabulary)?

**Second Example:**

```
import keras
import numpy as np

from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, LSTM, Dense
from keras.models import Model

# The first input
main_input = Input(shape=(100,), dtype='int32', name='main_input')

# This embedding layer will encode the input sequence
# into a sequence of dense 512-dimensional vectors.
x = Embedding(output_dim=512, input_dim=10000, input_length=100)(main_input)

# A LSTM will transform the vector sequence into a single vector,
# containing information about the entire sequence
lstm_out = LSTM(32)(x)

auxiliary_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='aux_output')(lstm_out)

# Second input
auxiliary_input = Input(shape=(5,), name='aux_input')
x = keras.layers.concatenate([lstm_out, auxiliary_input])

# We stack a deep densely-connected network on top
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)

# And finally we add the main logistic regression layer
main_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(x)

model = Model(inputs=[main_input, auxiliary_input], outputs=[main_output, auxiliary_output])

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy',
              loss_weights=[1., 0.2])

headline_data = np.random.random((1000, 100))
additional_data = np.random.random((1000, 5))
labels = np.random.random((1000, 1))

model.fit([headline_data, additional_data], [labels, labels],
          epochs=50, batch_size=32)
```

Here the input dimension is set to be 10,000 but again we are dealing with an input (headline_data) which has potentially 1000 x 100 = 100,000 unique values.  How can we represent these 100,000 values using a 10,000 dimensional input space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have misunderstood the Embedding layer. Let me describe it briefly:

You can look at the Embedding layer as a look-up table: it takes an **integer** as input, and returns a **vector** *corresponding to the given integer* as output. So in context of NLP, usually those integers correspond to tokens or words in a dictionary which we have created from training data. For example, this dictionary may look like this:

```
hi:     1
you:    2
hello:  3
can:    4
are:    5
how:    6
...
```

So for example the word "hi" has been assigned the number "1" to it. Now, if we want to represent the sentence `"hi how are you"` it would be equivalent to `[1, 6, 5, 2]`. This integer vector is the input of our model and it will be given to the Embedding layer as input. The Embedding layer in return would give the corresponding vectors. For example, the embedding vectors in the Embedding layer, at a certain point during training, may look like this:

```
1:  [0.43, 0.09, 0.13, 1.65]
2:  [0.43, 0.11, 0.23, -1.75]
3:  [-0.88, 0.19, 2.33, 0.55]
4:  [0.93, 0.79, -0.23, 2.05]
5:  [0.27, 0.61, 0.10, 0.85]
6:  [0.03, 1.09, -3.19, 2.25]
...
```

So for `"hi how are you"` it returns the following vectors:

```
[[0.43, 0.09, 0.13, 1.65],
 [0.03, 1.09, -3.19, 2.25],
 [0.27, 0.61, 0.10, 0.85],
 [0.43, 0.11, 0.23, -1.75]]
```

Now you can better understand what those parameters of the Embedding layer correspond to: the `input_dim` actually is the number of entries in the look-up table which is equivalent to the number of **unique words** in our dictionary, and the `output_dim` is the dimension (i.e. length) of embedding vectors in the Embedding layer (in above example, the length of each vector is 4 so the `output_dim=4`).

As a side note, both of the example codes you have provided would not work. That's because the input of your model (i.e. `x_train` and `x_test`) does not consist of integers; rather they are arrays of float numbers (due to using `np.random.random`), which is not acceptable when you have an Embedding layer as the first layer of your model.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly my understanding.  I was confused by the post though and thought that something I did not get right.